# How do I declare a composite primary key in the Lumen Model?

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have a table with three primary keys, I'm trying to create a model for it, and I'd like to use the find () function, but it throws the error:

Code:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Visit extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'ft_visit';

  protected $primaryKey = ['sk_time', 'sk_region', 'sk_device'];

  protected $fillable = [
      'sk_time', 'sk_region', 'sk_device', 'ds_page',
  ];

  public $timestamps = false;

  public function time()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Time::class, 'sk_time');
  }
}
```

Error:

```
(1/1) ErrorException
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: Eloquent doesn't support composite keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the solution presented in this article [Solved: Eloquent doesn’t support composite primary keys.](https://blog.maqe.com/solved-eloquent-doesnt-support-composite-primary-keys-62b740120f)

Adding the `setKeysForSaveQuery` method below on your model, and removing the `$primaryKey` attribute, you might be able to add this otherwise not supported functionality to your Eloquent model.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class Visit extends Model {

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $query
            ->where('sk_time', '=', $this->getAttribute('sk_time'))
            ->where('sk_region', '=', $this->getAttribute('sk_region'));
            ->where('sk_device', '=', $this->getAttribute('sk_device'));

        return $query;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** As noted by @Devon this might affect Eloquent in other ways and should be ***tested thoroughly*** before use. However, this should give you some clearance on the way to solve it, should you not be in a position where you can (preferably) restructure the application or data.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that,  it may work for saving, but what about for relationships and everything else Eloquent is set up to handle?  You'll just lead yourself into some hard to diagnose bugs later.

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent does not support composite keys.  The best thing to do in this scenario to ensure Eloquent compatibility is to convert your existing primary composite key to a unique composite key and add an autoincrement primary key (id) for Eloquent to use.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. Laravel and lumen (using Eloquent) do not support composite keys.